# Could not find class RestAdapter Builder

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i've been having some problems with an android code i'm making... I've two projects one in android and another that's only java code. I'd troubles importing two second one to the first one, needed two manually add all JARs.. and finally is working but I'm using RestAdapter and when it executes... tells me that could not find restadapter.builder

This is my code in MainActivity.java

```
               String TEST_URL = "http://localhost:8080";
                RestAdapter personService = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(TEST_URL).setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).build()
                        .create(PersonSvcApi.class);
```

I dont understand why it tells me its not able to reference... because i have in my project gson and retrofit jars... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
RestAdapter personService = new ...,
```

try:

```
PersonSvcApi personService = new ...
```

The RestAdapter object type should match the class referenced in the .create( ) part.